# How to create ImageView with multiple images switching and deleting chosen one?

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimageview

I have an imageView with multiple images switching every 5 seconds.How would I go about adding a button to my project that deletes the picture that is currently on screen and continues switching amongst the left over images? So far I have the code below and thanks!

```
  var uiimageArray = [UIImage]()

@IBOutlet weak var customImageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    uiimageArray += [UIImage(named: "img1")!, UIImage(named:"img2")!, UIImage(named:"img3")!, UIImage(named:"img4")!,UIImage(named:"img5")!,UIImage(named:"img6")!]

    customImageView.animationImages = uiimageArray
    customImageView.animationDuration = 5
    customImageView.startAnimating()




}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below

**Objective C**

```
for (UIImage *image in contentArray) {

    if ([imageView.image isEqual:image]) {

        [contentArray removeObject:image];
    }
}
```

**Swift Version :**

```
    for image in contentArray {

        if ((customImageView.image? .isEqual(image)) != false) {

            image.removeObject(contentArray)
        }
    }
```

You can check with that image to find out which image is currently being visible in that imageView.

Hope it helps..

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am trying to create a button that deletes the current image on screen then continues displaying the rest. Any ideas?

Comment: Remove that selected image from array. So that next time that image wont be available in array. then wont display in Image View.

Comment: Updated the answer. If you are satisfied, mark as Selected Answer.

Comment: Ok but you are checking for one specific image. I have multiple images that need to checked for?

Comment: also I am programming in Swift not Objective C

Comment: Updated answer. Check it out.

Comment: There is no method "removeObject" in Swift from what the compiler is saying

Comment: Change your image Array to NSMutableArray from NSArray.

Answer (score 0):

On button click get the currentImage from imageView and delete it from array.

```
@IBAction func btnClick(sender: UIButton) {
    var currentImage = customImageView.image
    if contains(imageArray, currentImage) { 
        imageArray.removeObjectsInArray(currentImage)
    }

}
```

For deleting objects from array you need to write an extension method as below:

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable { 
    mutating func removeObject(object: Element) { 
        if let index = self.indexOf(object) { 
           self.removeAtIndex(index)
        } 
    } 

    mutating func removeObjectsInArray(array: [Element]) { 
        for object in array { 
            self.removeObject(object) 
        } 
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can see CAKeyFrameAnimation also as it has delegate method to work on.

Comment: Your first answer does not work because "removeObjectInArray" does not exist in Swift. Please modify it

Comment: Correct the method to removeObjectsInArray. Also you have to create an extension.